# Is person who has lost family last name still considered Direct descendant

Tags: surnames, family-tree

My aunt's children, already have children, and these kids no longer have any of my grandparents' last names, as they have inherited the lastname from the husband.

Can they still be considered as **Direct Descendants** even though they no longer have the grandparents' last name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the English Stack Exchange I found a definition for "direct descendant" at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61559/meaning-of-direct-descendant-as-opposed-to-indirect-descendant:

> A direct descendent is someone who can trace their lineage by "child"
> relationships all the way back to the desired ancestor. A non-direct
> descendent has to go through a "cousin" or a "by marriage" or some
> other non-child relationship in order to find the desired ancestor.

This matches my understanding of the term and since your aunt's children (and grandchildren) are children (and grandchildren) of your aunt who is a child of your grandparents they are direct descendants of your grandparents.  A person's surname is irrelevant to any determination of who their parent is when determining direct desendants.

Answer (score 0):

What do you consider a "direct descendant"?

Your aunt's children are your grandparent's grandchildren, are they not?

If one of your sons decided to change his name, would he still be your descendant?

(Not strictly an answer, I know...)